# Why flaging low quality questions option isn't avaiable?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to flag [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4422/can-a-piece-not-a-pawn-capture-en-passant) as a low quality question but there's no such option. Why?

On that particular question, I  see it today, not yesterday, so I picked another question and took screenshots, voila that's what I saw yesterday

[image]

and

[image]

And it's not in the `closing` section either

Comment: What options do you see when you try to flag it?

Comment: @EdDean go to so or whatever try to flag any question, there's an option (this question should be closed because  - low quality) im on phone can't take screenshots

Comment: Right, and I myself see a low quality option if I try to flag the particular question linked to above. But you don't?

Comment: @EdDean please read my edit

Comment: Interesting. It *might* be that the very low quality option isn't available for flagging because the post in question has received one upvote. I found some similar discussion regarding flagging answers at least: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220620/why-is-it-not-possible-to-flag-an-upvoted-answer-as-low-quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "very low quality" flag is not available on a post which has a positive score. See the [meta SE question: Why is it not possible to flag an upvoted answer as Low Quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220620/164012) which Ed linked up there in the comments.

> If the post has been found useful by someone else, you need to make a stronger case for it being "very low quality" - there's a reasonable chance that *it isn't*. In the past, folks repeatedly used this flag on answers that were perfectly well-written but also wrong - that's not a reason to flag, it's a reason to *down-vote* (and perhaps leave a comment describing the problem).

Comment: It's worth repeating that VLQ is for *severe formatting/content problems*. In the context of the flag, *content problems* means "this is ugly and degrades our site purely by its very existence". It does NOT mean "this post is bad, and the poster should feel bad". If the post is merely bad, the correct course of action is a downvote, with a comment if you are so inclined. (To be fair, the original question was probably a decent candidate for the flag, so this comment is more in the nature of general guidance.)